# Undefined reference to boost while building Rose

Tags: ubuntu, boost, 64-bit

I'm attempting to build Rose, and after following the instructions on Rose's website for installing all of the dependencies, I'm still having trouble with the following error after executing the "make" command:

```
/home/jbeel/rose_build/src/.libs/librose.so: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::flags() const'
/home/jbeel/rose_build/src/.libs/librose.so: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::mapped_file_source()'
/home/jbeel/rose_build/src/.libs/librose.so: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::size() const'
/home/jbeel/rose_build/src/.libs/librose.so: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::data() const'
/home/jbeel/rose_build/src/.libs/librose.so: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open_impl(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<boost::iostreams::detail::path> const&)'
```

And I'm at a loss for what might be causing it. Are there any possible solutions? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: You need to link it with boost iostream library `-llibboost_iostreams`

Comment: And you'll need to install `boost` if you haven't already done so: `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev`